# Shiny App in RStudio Won't Load Despite Having Downgraded

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

Currently I'm trying to run an example shiny app, that was given to me. Some colleagues have confirmed that the app is able to run in their computers, but I cannot for the life of me get the app to run. I have installed "shiny" and "shinydashboards" but once I press "Run App" in RStudio, the console simply displays:

```
shiny::runApp('Path')
Loading required package: shiny
```

and RStudio never opens any additional windows. The strange part is that it's not like RStudio is hanging, as you can still edit code but not compile it. In other posts I saw that this was solved in other cases by returning to an older version of shiny or RStudio. I have tried returning to shiny 1.5 and RStudio 1.13 but to no avail.

This is the information from the "sessionInfo()" command

```
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5 tools_4.0.5    tinytex_0.30   xfun_0.22
```

Comment: What OS are you using? And what R version? The output of `sessionInfo()` should show all the relevant packages (after you try to run the app)

Comment: Thank you! I updated the post to add the information from "sessionInfo()". The relevant packages are "shiny", "shinydashboards" and "reticulate".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the package "Rcpp" not being installed correctly. After running the following command

```
install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = T)
```

everything went back to normal. In my case, the dependencies were necesary to make it work. It may change from person to person.